# Play a video with MediaElement and download it too

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I want to play a video from the web in MediaElement and in the same time to download the video too.

I try to do it with setting Stream as the source but it won't work. It is possible to do it?

---

EDIT:

This is what i do for now,the problem is that i want to start playing from the start and not when i finish download the file:

```
    public void StartDownloadFile(string aVideoUrl,string aId)
    {
        this.VideoUrl = aVideoUrl;
        this.id = aId;

        startPlaying = false;

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(this.VideoUrl));
    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Result != null)
            {

                #region Isolated Storage Copy Code
                isolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                bool checkQuotaIncrease = this.IncreaseIsolatedStorageSpace(e.Result.Length);

                string VideoFile = "VideoCache\\" + this.id + ".wmv";
                isolatedStorageFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(VideoFile, FileMode.Create, isolatedStorageFile);
                long VideoFileLength = (long)e.Result.Length;
                byte[] byteImage = new byte[VideoFileLength];
                e.Result.Read(byteImage, 0, byteImage.Length);
                isolatedStorageFileStream.Write(byteImage, 0, byteImage.Length);

                #endregion

                callbackFinish();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            callbackDidUpdate((double)e.ProgressPercentage);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you currently have so we may suggest improvements. Also please explain 'wont work', an exception? which type? which line of code?

Comment: I edit my post with the code

Comment: @MTA, I'm afraid, that's not possible for now. If you examine [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190669(v=vs.95).aspx) article, you can see a remark: "Use this method rather than setting the Source to a URI for cases **where you already have the media available as a stream**." I've also asked such question sometime, and couldn't find a way to do it via MediaElement.